# What is the local scope of definite articles in claims?

Tags: claims, dependent-claim

I mean scope in the programming sense, not the claim scope sense.

For example, if I have claims like:

1. The system comprising an A.
2. The system of claim 1, wherein the A includes a B.

Clearly, if the next dependent claim depends on 2, it inherits "the" from B:

3. The system of claim 2, wherein the B includes a C.

But what about another dependent claim that depends on the independent claim?  Does it inherit "the" from another dependent claim, in a different branch of the claim tree?

For example, which is correct for the next dependent claim?

4. The system of claim 1, wherein the A includes a B and an X.

or

4. The system of claim 1, wherein the A includes the B and an X.

Answer (score 1):

Each depend claim has the meaning as if all the claims in its path back to the independent claim are incorporated. Claim 4 could *not* be

> The system of claim 1, wherein the A includes the B and an X.

because B has not been introduced. Claim 4 has no connection with claim 2 or 3. This is an area of patent law that is completely logical.